# Binding data with pragma query

Tags: sqlite, laravel-4

I'm starting to develop a website with Laravel/SQLite.

I need to display some information from my database structure, so I'm trying to use `PRAGMA` statements that SQLite provides.

My question is : **can I use the binding tool with pragma queries ?**

The bad-old school method works fine :

```
    DB::select('PRAGMA table_info(\''.$value->name.'\')');
```

If I try to use binding :

```
    DB::select('PRAGMA table_info( ? )', array($value->name));
```

I get this error :

```
    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "?": syntax error (SQL: PRAGMA table_info( migrations ))
```

I don't see in documentation if binding with DB's specific queries is allowed or not. I don't think so, but I don't find any documentation of the binding tool, so maybe I've done a mistake.

Comment: Bound parameters do not work with pragma statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are [placeholders for an expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).
A table name (whether in a PRAGMA or in any other statement) is not an expression but an identifer, so it cannot be bound to a parameter.

Comment: I don't understand. The binding method is provided by Laravel, what prevent them to replace the question mark with the correct string ?

Comment: The binds are handled not by Laravel but by the database. (This is required to handle control characters or blobs correctly.)